# Have MVC DropDownList submit pass command parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a Submit button on my MVC form like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="command" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
```

My controller catches the command string like this:

```
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Create(ProjectCreate model, string command)
{
    //...
    if (command == "Submit")
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

I would like my DropDownList to pass a command string as well. Right now I have the DropDownList do a submit like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CallForContentFormId, Model.CallForPaperFormsSelect(), new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
```

How do I set up the DropDownList to pass a command string when it submits?

Comment: One option is to put the value of the dropdownlist as a parameter in the URL.

Comment: If I collect that, it is collected on every submit. I'm trying to tell what control is doing the Submit. Is this a post from the Submit button or the dropdownlist or another control.

Comment: Add a hidden field?

Comment: If you are only submitting from either the input button or the drop down, you could just put an else block after your if block, since logically if the submit button is not submitting the form then it must be the drop down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems a little strange.
But following my suggestion, would could be something like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m =>
    m.CallForContentFormId,
    Model.CallForPaperFormsSelect(),
    new {
        @class = "form-control",
        @onchange="this.form.action+='?command=CallForContentFormId'; this.form.submit();"
})
```

Comment: Actually used this: `@onchange = "this.form.action+='?command=CallForContentFormId'; this.form.submit();" })` It needed single quotes.